# ‘struct dentry’ has no member named ‘d_count’ When compiling 3.10 kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, google-chrome-os

I'm attempting to compile a custom 3.10 kernel for my Acer Chromebook 13, but I've hit a road block.
The compilation fails with

```
fs/configfs/dir.c: In function ‘remove_dir’:
fs/configfs/dir.c:390:2: error: ‘struct dentry’ has no member named ‘d_count’
make[2]: *** [fs/configfs/dir.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [fs/configfs] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

`dir.c` can be found [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/kernel/+/refs/heads/chromeos-3.10/fs/configfs/dir.c)

---

I am compiling the kernel using

```
LOADADDR=0x02000000 make -j5 zImage uImage dtbs modules CC="gcc-4.7"
```

Natively from `armv7l`, my `.config` can be found [here](https://hastebin.com/elexirowip.ini)

---

I've tried using newer, and older versions of `dir.c` but they only cause other errors.

Comment: Well, the definition of the [struct dentry](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/kernel/+/refs/heads/chromeos-3.10/include/linux/dcache.h#106) actually doesn't contain `d_count` field. That field has been replaced with `d_refcount` one, and for obtain count one need to call `d_count` function instead. It seems, they "backported" a `d_refcount` field from the 3.11 version of vanilla kernel, but forgot to update usages of this field. See e.g. 3.11 version of the vanilla [fs/configfs/dir.c:390](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.11/source/fs/configfs/dir.c#L390).

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev, this looks like it could be a fix, I'll rebuild after changing the source.